# Continue eating food after siren

Tags: halal-haram, ramadan

In India, is it permissible to continue eating food after the siren of suhoor is heard ? I am extremely confused about this matter since a lot of time .

Comment: In india or anywhere around the world, principle to follow suhoor timing not siron or something, but if you are sure siron is buzzed on the correct sahr time, than you should stop eating when siren begins. No one can tell if siron buzzed on suhoor time or not, but you can check.

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal please answer question in answer section. If you don't even have resources. Comments are intent to understand and explain questions not for answers.

Comment: @Medi1Saif please answer question in answer section. If you don't even have resources. Comments are intent to understand and explain questions not for answers.

Comment: maybe this? http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1905/when-should-one-stop-eating-and-drinking-and-what-is-the-ruling-on-one-who-has

Answer (score 0):

As I have heard that about eating suhoor after siren is extended due to time difference. For example if the siren is buzzed from Delhi and people of Madras city hear it through radio or other sources will extend a little more because of time difference. That's simple and understandable.